# Downgrade Mariadb to 10.1 on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: apt, downgrade, mariadb

I recently upgraded my main Ubuntu install from Ubuntu 18.04 to 19.10 mainly for testing within my company to make sure the currently used software stack will be compatible come 20.04

Everything is working well however we are yet to upgrade the database some of our internal applications past Mariadb 10.1

Be default Ubuntu 19.10 ships with 10.3, I can't seem to find any details to get the downgrade to 10.1. I plan to push forward everyone upgrading to 10.3 at least however until thats done I need to be able to interact with datasets etc from the 10.1 server.

So my question is can I downgrade back to 10.1 on Ubuntu 19.10 and if not, short of a complete reinstall of 18.04 what methods would people suggest to get a local Mariadb 10.1 instance running. Docker maybe?

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is can I downgrade back to 10.1 on Ubuntu 19.10

Yes, but it is not a downgrade. It is a re-install.

- Dump your current databases to a backup
- `service mysql stop`
- Purge mariadb and remove any PPA you installed with it
- Install the mariadb PPA that holds 10.1. You can add the 10.1 PPA with:

  ```
  apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0xF1656F24C74CD1D8
  add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,i386,ppc64el] http://ftp.hosteurope.de/mirror/mariadb.org/repo/10.1/ubuntu xenial main'
  sudo apt update
  service mysql stop
  ```

And you can then install 10.1.

---

The complete removal and installation command would be (the `-` at the end of a package means to delete it)

```
sudo apt install --purge mariadb-client-10.2- mariadb-client-core-10.2- 
  mariadb-server-10.2- mariadb-server-core-10.2- mariadb-client-10.1 
  mariadb-client-core-10.1 mariadb-server-10.1 mariadb-server-core-10.1
  libmariadbclient18 libjemalloc1 libmysqlclient18
```

After installation you need to upload your backup database.